# New google calendar, "pop-out" events, if they don't fit in the defined area

Tags: jquery, google-calendar-api

Take a look at what the new google calendar does when there are too many events to fit in the defined square.  You can click the `+2 more` link (or whatever it may say), and the square pops out a bit... and displays everything.

Does anyone know of a JS/JQuery library that has this functionality?

Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGQUr.png

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a screen shot or provide more detail?  I can't tell what you are talking about.  What do you mean by "the defined square"?

Comment: @gilly3 http://i.imgur.com/86tom.png

Comment: Sounds like you would create the "new" element higher up in the DOM (possibly child of body level) and then position it over the existing box as appropriate. But no, I don't know of a library that has this functionality.

Comment: @BlairMcMillan - Yea, was hoping there'd be some systematic way to do this... it's a little over my head right now in experience =(... ha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the pop out box, you could use a [jQueryUI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) and position it where you want it.  Re-style it to match your UI, of course.

If you are also hoping to get the logic to figure out how many items are hidden, and display a "+n more..." message there, that seems like it could be a little specific for a plugin, but maybe not.

Here's one simple implementation.  http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/sxGSr/  There's a bit of hard-coding that could be made more dynamic, but this may give you a start.

Comment: this is pretty awesome.  I can probably play with it from here and get exactly what I need I think.... Thanks man!

Comment: Question for ya.  How can I resize the entire box that is displayed in the pop out.  If I change the width in the .ui CSS definitions that you have, it only resizes inside the box - and not the total box size...  Mainly I'm looking at width here.

Comment: also, another issue.  This is a table and it has multiple cases where this will exist inside the table.  Right now, it only applies this effect to the FIRST instance.  How can I make this apply to ALL instances where div id's = inner and outer?

Comment: I fixed the width issue, but the bigger issue of only one per page I cannot figure out.  FYI. thanks Gilly.

Comment: @Shackrock - Use classes instead of ids (ids must be unique per element).  Use `.each()` to iterate the elements and apply the behavior.  Here's an updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/sxGSr/1/

Comment: That worked out pretty well.  Now, however, I have an issue with the pop out when used with jQuery table that is sortable/filterable/etc...  Take a look at this: http://i.imgur.com/rLYEK.png .  The pop out goes where it was when the page first loaded, not after sort... so it's like the position doesn't follow the box.  Any ideas?

Comment: Do the positioning in the click handler with `.dialog("option", { position: newPosition })`:  http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/sxGSr/3/

Comment: ok, we're really really close now... take a look at this screen shot: http://i.imgur.com/gbWZg.png .  If I scroll down, and click the See More... link, the pop up is not in the correct place (above, it should have been placed at the very top box where the first "see more..." link is located).  Yet - If my screen is at the top when I click it (even after sorting), we're fine, no issues.  Not sure why the scrolling on the page would have an effect?

Comment: @Shackrock - Tough to say without seeing your code.  Open a new question specific to positioning a jQueryUI dialog.  Make sure to include your relevant code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7682018/jquery-dialog-pop-outs-positioning-issue-when-scrolling-down-the-page