# jQuery Dialog Pop outs - positioning issue when scrolling down the page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

After getting a good start here: [New google calendar, "pop-out" events, if they don't fit in the defined area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604301/new-google-calendar-pop-out-events-if-they-dont-fit-in-the-defined-area/7613823) , I now have some further questions and issues to hammer out.

Here is the jQuery Code:

```
// Google-Calendar-Style pop-outs
        $(function() {
            $(".inner").each(function() {
                var inner = $(this);
                var popout = inner.clone().removeClass("inner");
                popout.dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    draggable: false,
                    resizable: false,
                    width: 150
                });
                var plusMore = $("<div><a href='#' onmouseover='this.style.cursor=\'pointer\''>See More...</a></div>");
                plusMore.insertBefore(inner.find("> div:eq(1)"));
                plusMore.click(function() {
                    var pos = inner.offset();
                    popout.dialog("option", {
                        position: [pos.left - 6, pos.top - 4]
                    }).dialog("open");
                });
            });
        });
```

Here is the CSS related to this:

```
<style type="text/css">
        .outer {
            height: 45px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .inner > h1 {
            margin: 0;
            font-size: 1em;
        }
        .ui-widget.ui-dialog {
            font-size: 1em;
            font-family: inherit;
            padding: 2px 5px;
        }
        .ui-dialog div.ui-dialog-titlebar {
            padding: 0;
            background: transparent none;
            border-width: 0;
        }
        .ui-dialog div.ui-dialog-content {
            padding: 0;
        }
    </style>
```

Here is the HTML (note, I actually use Smarty to loop some arrays here, but this is the base...  the inner most `<div>` is repeated with each loop (user) (so there is one `outer` and one `inner`, per cell):

```
<div class="outer"> 
  <div class="inner">
   <div>
       <a href=Tenant.php" style="text-decoration:none">{$tenant.firstName} {$tenant.lastName}</a><br>
       &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="Message.php">Send Message</a><br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a screenshot with two problems I'd like to fix.

1. When I scroll down the page (even one tiny bit), and then click "see more..." - the pop up is not in the correct location.  As seen in the image below, it should have been over the very first row/box - but instead it dropped down a lot lower.  Don't be fooled and think it ended up aligned to box #4 - that is just a coincidence, because even the last entry in the table will have the box the same amount lower on the screen - and NOT aligned.  `There is NO issue if my scroll bar is at the very top of the page.`
2. I would like to get rid of the space for the top title.  I just want the list of users and links to begin at the top - on the same row as the pop-up box's "X."

[image: Here is the issue I'm seeing]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQueryUI positions dialogs relative to the viewport instead of the document, so you need to account for the scroll in your calculation.  Use `$(document).scrollTop()`:

```
popout.dialog("option", {
    position: [
        pos.left - 6 - $(document).scrollLeft(),
        pos.top - 4 - $(document).scrollTop()
    ]
});
```

Comment: That does position things correctly.  Is there a way to make the page NOT scroll to the top after clicking my "see more..." link?  Right now, it forces the scroll bar back to the top instead of remaining in the same place.  Further, I still can't seem to get that title row to go away without weird things happening all around...

Comment: just an update.  I got the "Scroll to stop" problem to stop by using `return false` after I opened the dialogue.  I still can't get the title to work right...

Comment: I can hide the title by using: `.ui-dialog-titlebar { display:none; }`, but this also hides the `X` button. I think that if I'm able to assign an ID to the popouts, I can use $("#MyID").dialog("close") to make the dialogue close when I click anywhere....

Comment: and how can I find out my dialog's ID?